# pass parameters to other analyses using a direct databse request in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I am using OBIEE 11g. I have an analyse with direct database request. In that analyse I have a column emplid. 
I have put a interaction link on this column that bring me to another analyse. 
Unfortunatelly the parameter emplid='selected value' isn't passing true the other analyse where there is also a column emplid. 
I think it is normal, because OBIEE can not know that the emplid columns are the same. 
I can't define the emplid value of my direct database request as a presentation variable, because (if I am not wrong) you can only define a prompt as a presentation variable. 
How can I pass the value then to my other analyse?

Answer (score 0):

Direct DB requests are extremely limited in what they allow. If you want to pass the value, then you need to use the Go URL method:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIEIT/apiwebintegrate.htm#BIEIT353